# Having issues with GoLang and AWS APIGatewayProxyRequest not being populated

Tags: go

Been at this for a few hours now. No matter what i try the request.HTTPMethod is coming over as "". Code is posted below. I started off with examples off posts online then just went from complex to something simple and still not getting why the request is coming over as black all the time... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    if request.HTTPMethod == "POST" {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: "yepp", StatusCode: 200}, nil
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: "nope", StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the reason/fix... In the API Gateway setup I had not turned on the 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' flag. Without this it seems AWS will not forward the request information down go figure.

Comment: Just struggled with this problem myself for almost 2hrs... Really confusing, especially since you don't even see this option when creating a resource.